# Characterize the metric spaces whose open sets form a $\sigma$-algebra.

Tags: measure-theory, metric-spaces

**Characterize the metric spaces whose open sets form a $\sigma$-algebra.**

I have found this exercise in measure theory and found it interesting. So I want to solve it, but it has been a bit difficult for me because I don't know how to characterize these spaces yet. I understand that "characterize" means to find a simple description of the things in question, or rather, to find a simpler property that holds for a metric space if and only if its open sets constitute a sigma algebra.

On the other hand, in my searches for a suggestion, I found the following:

"The $\sigma$-algebra also contains all the closed sets. What does it say about the metric space if every one-point set $\{x\}$ is open?"

But I still don't understand that I can conclude with this.
Alternatively, I have $$\{x\}= \bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}}B_{1/n}(x),$$ and a $\sigma$-algebra is closed under countable intersections.

I do not know if all this leads to the correct path to characterize these spaces, but I appreciate any help that you can give me on this problem.

Comment: Are you asking what you can conclude from the fact that $\{x\}$ is open? That would mean that $x$ is an isolated point

Comment: If every singleton set is open, then every subset is open. What do you call this topology?

Comment: @saulspatz Is a singleton set in a metric space necessarily closed?

Comment: Yes, because its complement is open.  If $y\neq x$ then $\delta=d(x,y)\neq 0$ so $x\notin B(y, \delta/2)\subseteq\{x\}^c$.

Comment: @saulspatz I'm tempted to say that it is enough that each point in the metric space is isolated, (that's what my intuition says), but I don't know how to justify this formally.

Comment: @hgmath The question is really about the metric space, not about singleton sets.

Comment: You've proved that every point is isolated.  I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: @saulspatz Sorry for not making me understand, but what I really have not understood is why is it enough that each point of the metric space is isolated? Or rather, how can one write this characterization formally?

Comment: If each point is isolated, then every set is open.  This is called the discrete topology.  In metric space terms, the topology is induced by the trivial metric $$d(x,y)=\begin{cases}0&x=y\\1,&x\neq y\end{cases}$$

Comment: @saulspatz  Let (X, d) be a metric space. So its open sets form a $\sigma$-algebra if and only if (x, d) is a discrete space.  Is this characterization correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.